# The sides of a regular triangle are bicolored . Do there exist on its perimeter three monochromatic vertices of a right angled triangle?

Tags: combinatorics

The sides of a regular triangle are bicolored . Do there exist on its perimeter three monochromatic vertices of a  right angled triangle ?
The solution given on Problem Solving Strategies by Arthur Engel is as follows:

> Suppose there is no vertices of the same color. Partition each side of a regular triangle into three parts of equal length. These points are vertices of a regular hexagon . If two of it's opposite vertices are of the same color,then all other vertices are of the other color and hence there exists a right angled triangle of other color . Hence ,opposite sides of a hexagon are of different color. Thus there exist two neighboring vertices of different colors. One pair of these bicolored vertices lies on a side of the triangle . The points of this side  differing from the vertices of the hexagon,cannot be of the first or second color . Contradiction.

However, I don't get the part where it says "If two of it's opposite vertices are of the same color,then all other vertices are of the other color" . The question specifically asks for a right triangle. What do they mean by "opposite vertices"? Furthermore, if we consider two "non- neighboring vertices" as opposite vertices then if both of them are of same color and the remaining of different colors, we will surely get a monochromatic triangle but how do we gurantee that it will be a  right triangle?Now, for the rest part of the solution it plainly assumes that we will have "opposite sides of a hexagon are of different color. Thus there exist two neighboring vertices of different colors." However, after that they are basically saying that "One pair of these bicolored vertices lies on a side of the triangle . The points of this side  differing from the vertices of the hexagon,cannot be of the first or second color ." What do they mean by this statement? I am not  really getting it.

Comment: The solution is considering the six vertices of a regular hexagon, all of which are on the perimeter of a regular triangle. Avoiding a monochromatic right triangle among these vertices forces a monochromatic right triangle having two of these vertices and one vertex of the regular triangle.

Comment: @Daniel Mathias How can you say that all those six points when joined with each other gives a monochromatic triangle for each join of those $ 3 $ points among those six points in the monochromatic triangle ....because if that is not true then we cannot say that  by keeping two vertices of same color and rest of different colors we get a monochromatic  right triangle ....

Comment: Draw it on paper. Color two points of the hexagon red, the other four points blue. There will be a right triangle with three blue vertices.

Comment: @Daniel Mathias Two points on opposite side(by opposite sides I mean non-neighboring points) or on the similar sides. If on same side then yeah, we get a monochromatic blue triangle but how do we prove it is a right angled triangle? Same goes for the opposite side case, we do get a monochromatic blue  triangle but how do we know that it will be right angled triangle or not?

Comment: The points are on a *regular hexagon* If you don't understand this, then I cannot help you.

Comment: @Daniel Mathais Of course the points are on a "regular hexagon" ....we can see it....but I am basically asking for a "confirmation " that the triangles formed LEAVING ASIDE THOSE TWO SIMILAR COLORED POINTS ARE RIGHT TRIANGLE OR NOT???IS THIS EVIDENT FROM A PROPERTY OF REGULAR HEXAGON ...THAT IS WHAT I WANT TO  KNOW ABOUT ???..??....AND THAT IS NOT ALL I WAS ASKING ALSO ABOUT THE NEXT PORTION OF THE SOLUTION....A RATHER DETAILED EXPLANATION FOR IT ...

Answer (score 2):

Consider the regular hexagon and triangle below.  $A$ and $D$ are opposite points on the hexagon.  If they are both red, coloring any third vertex of the hexagon red would make a right triangle of red points.  If all the other vertices are blue, $BEF$ is a blue right triangle.  This shows all opposite pairs of points on the hexagon are different colors.  You then have a pair of vertices on one side of the triangle, say $A,B$ that are different colors.  If $A$ is red, $B$ is blue, then by the earlier argument $D$ is blue and $E$ is red.  Now if $G$ is red we have $AEG$ as a red right triangle and if $G$ is blue we have $BDG$ as a blue right triangle.

[image]